# How to change the series plot display inside the scrollbar of the RangeSelector in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It's showing the first yAxis plot by default can we change the series display inside it ?It is showing SP500 but i want to show LT/ST plot.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `showInNavigator` property:

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        showInNavigator: false
    }, {
        ...,
        showInNavigator: true
    }, {
        ..
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ftnbe5o0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.showInNavigator